# .style file cause error "Path must be a string. Received undefined" with UglifyJSPlugin --optimize-minimize

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I am using webpack with following config file：

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'index': './index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: './dist/[name].min.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.styl$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!autoprefixer!stylus-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./dist/[name].min.css'),
    new UglifyJSPlugin( {  minimize: true })
  ]
}
```

and when I type

> webpack  --config ./min.config.js

it runs well and I saw the .js file created. However when I type

> webpack --optimize-minimize --config ./min.config.js

I got following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/stylus-loader!./index.styl
Module build failed: TypeError: /home/test/index.styl:3:1
   1| @import '~normalize.css/normalize.css'
   2| @import './style'
   3|
------^

Path must be a string. Received undefined

    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at extname (path.js:1431:5)
    at new SourceMapper (/home/test/node_modules/stylus-loader/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/sourcemapper.js:41:7)
    at Renderer.render (/home/test/node_modules/stylus-loader/node_modules/stylus/lib/renderer.js:94:9)
    at /home/test/node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js:149:12
    at tryCatchReject (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:840:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:799:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:590:4)
    at Pending.run (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:481:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)
    at Scheduler.drain (/home/test/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:27:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 @ ./index.styl 4:14-156
```

How to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by this `test: /\.styl$/,` ?

Comment: [http://stylus-lang.com/ ]
`Stylus is an innovative stylesheet language that compiles down to CSS. Inspired by SASS, Stylus is built with node.js and capable of running in the browser ...`

Comment: I mean its extension of file we refer in the code above so what do you mean by `.styl$` this should be [executable file](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/executable.html) for server, here it should be `.CSS` only